# I'd like to know some more details on the table sent down to prophet 'Isa?

Tags: quran, tafseer, reference-request, prophet-isa, ahlul-kitab

I've lately heard a lesson or lecture on the tafseer of the verses telling the story of the table which was sent down to prophet 'Isa () which is quoted in [5:112-115](https://legacy.quran.com/5/112-115).

The wording of the qur'an suggests that the the companions of 'Isa () asked for this sign while in this lecture it was presented as a question asked in a great gathering of many thousand of people. Is there any backup for this?

The story in the qur'an seems to end with Allah's promise to send it down while in the lecture the content of food which was on the table was described I'd like to know if there's a backup for that too.

Above this the lecturer added more details such as that the companions of 'Isa () didn' t want to eat from it unless he ate etc. most of this content sounded to me as if it had none Islamic sources. But Allah know best.

Comment: Is this the same incident as described in the Bible (Final Supper)?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Supper